# how to setup wordpress blog on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress

I setup an aws EC2 instance and installed wordpress as mentioned in the docs.(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html)

I assigned a static external IP Elastic IP: 54.200.141.14 to the aws instance.

I registered a domain name http://www.techweblogs.co.uk/ and mapped domain techweblogs.co.uk to Elastic IP: 54.200.141.14

Everything went fine till now. When I access http://www.techweblogs.co.uk/ the Site is taking a long time to load...

Once the site is loaded all styling is now gone and the links points to `ec2-xx-xx-143-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

I don't know where am I going wrong. Pl. help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the correct URL in WordPress's General settings pane in both locations.